# Using Python maintain clean a text file on a specific format consistent across each line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dataframe

I have got a unique use case. I have got a txt file in the following format where every line starts with "APA" and ends with "||" (varies in length and content, does not matter)

```
APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|123||
APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|131|12r2gw||
APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|43s|12|123sdfq|prime||
```

In some lines however, due to unknown reasons, some of these lines are split like so:

```
APA lEDGER|5023|hello|
40937 / 903.01
for period: 2021|8|332.48||
```

Technically this line should have been like:

```
APA lEDGER|5023|hello|40937 / 903.01 for period: 2021|8|332.48||
```

The file is of really huge size (16MB), and this is the logic I have come up with:

Read each line into a list of strings and apply the following algorithm:

```
pattern = re.compile("\s*[^APA]")
patternOK = re.compile("\s*[APA]")

final_list = [] --list to store the cleaned strings
ptr=0
for elem in string_list:
    if(elem.startswith ("APA") and elem.endswith("||")):
        final_list.append(elem) --add each string with the proper format to the the final list
    
--maintain a pointer, point it to the current string and one to the previous string, if the current string does not start with an APA then append all the strings in a while loop and then append it back to the previous proper string

    if(ptr<len(string_list)):
        
        if (ptr - 1 >= 0):

            prev_el = str(string_list[ptr-1])
            
            curr_el = str(string_list[ptr])
            
           
            
            if(pattern.match(curr_el.strip())):
                
                
                while (pattern.match(string_list[ptr])):
                
                    prev_el = prev_el + '|'+string_list[ptr] 
                    ptr = ptr + 1
                    
                    
                    
                    if(ptr+1 > len(string_list)):
                        break
                        
                final_list.append(prev_el) --append the cleaned string to the final list
                
            
        
                
            
   
    ptr = timer+1
```

Mostly, it works. However, I could see some of the results were omitted or not in the order of insert. Please feel free to provide your own logic as well.

In summary, I need a list of strings with the correct format mentioned above.

Thanks

Comment: The 3rd line contains two '||' like this: "123sdfq||prime||" is it a typo?

Comment: Yes that’s a typo. Good call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you don't only have `||` at the end of the line, but also in between columns. If this is a typo, the normal `.split()` function would be sufficient, however if it's not, you can use `re.split()` to only split on `||` at the end of lines. Afterwards, remove the line breaks from the resulting list elements and finally join everything back together:

```
import re

data = """APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|123||
APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|131|12r2gw||
APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|43s|12|123sdfq||prime||
APA lEDGER|5023|hello|
40937 / 903.01
for period: 2021|8|332.48||
"""

r = re.compile(r'\|\|$', re.M)
splits = re.split(r, data)

clean_lines = (line.replace('\n', ' ').strip() for line in splits)
clean_file = '||\n'.join(clean_lines)

print(clean_file.splitlines())
```

Output:

```
['APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|123||',
 'APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|131|12r2gw||',
 'APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|43s|12|123sdfq||prime||',
 'APA lEDGER|5023|hello| 40937 / 903.01 for period: 2021|8|332.48||']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some tricks, like this.

[**Input**]

```
text = """APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|123||
APA lEDGER|1178|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|131|12r2gw||
APA lEDGER|9845|hello|
40937 / 903.01
for period: 2021|8|332.48||
APA lEDGER|9954|124223|STAFF
NAME|XYZ|43s|12|
123sdfq|
prime||
APA lEDGER|3649|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|123||
"""
```

[**Code**]

```
# One line to split,replace and join.
output= ''.join(text).replace('\n','').replace('||','||#').split('#')

# Print the output
print(output) 

# Save the output to a file
with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in output:
        f.write(f"{item}\n")
f.close()
```

[**Output**]

```
APA lEDGER|5023|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|123||
APA lEDGER|1178|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|131|12r2gw||
APA lEDGER|9845|hello|40937 / 903.01for period: 2021|8|332.48||
APA lEDGER|9954|124223|STAFFNAME|XYZ|43s|12|123sdfq|prime||
APA lEDGER|3649|124223|STAFF NAME|XYZ|123||
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file = open("file.txt.", "r")
file_out = open("file_out.txt", "w")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
my_line = ""
for line in lines:
    if (str(line.replace("\n", "")[-1]) + str(line.replace("\n", "")[-2])) != "||":
        my_line += line.replace("\n", "")
    else:
        my_line += line.replace("\n", "")
        file_out.write(my_line + "\n")
        my_line = ""
file_out.close()
```

I think this should work.
It will check if the line ends with "||". If it doesn't it will store the line and move to the next one. If the next one contains "||" at the end, it will write it to the output file, otherwise it will also move forward.
And I used `.replace("\n", "")` to remove the potential new line character.

Comment: This is perfect, but the lines seem to be joined together rather than on new separate lines. More specifically, when a line ends with "||" then the next item should start on a new separate line in the file_out.txt

Comment: Yes, sorry. I missed to add .replace("\n", "") to the condition. When you read a file, each line will contain "\n" at the end by default, so my condition of `line[-1]` and `line[-2]` would check accutally the `"\n"`. Now, using the `replace` function, it will work as you expect. I've updated the code, you can give it a try

Comment: Also, consider checking @AziMez response. If that works good, use it since It's more compact than this solution